# Why can't I move vertices?

Tags: interface

I'm a absolute beginner to Blender and I don't know how to move the vertices. I only have a one-click mouse. I tried to see others comment but no use. The <kbd>B</kbd> key doesn't work for my computer.

Comment: The selected vertices can be grabbed with `G`, but in general  I'd **highly** recommend using a three button mouse with blender.

Comment: Hi gandalf3, I don't have a three button mouse but thanks!

Comment: Another usable alternative to a 3-button mouse is a Magic Trackpad if you enable the "Emulate 3-button mouse" setting. It's a Mac-only solution, and requires some getting used to, but worth mentioning. (A 3-button mouse is still preferable)

Answer (score 1):

When you have selected a vertex, press <kbd>G</kbd> to move it.
But in your case I'm not sure you going to come far with a 1-click-mouse.
In addition it's a good idea to read the [blender documentation](http://www.blender.org/manual/) or watch some tutorials about blender on YouTube to get an idea of what you are doing.

Comment: Hi PEAR, I can't help but maybe whatever...OK, THANKS!

Comment: Hi PEAR, I can't even open ( www.blender.org/manual/)!!! But thanks!!! P.s. It is not a bug though>_<